# How to implement PATCH for a typeless entity model using OData 4 and WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

While creating a typeless entity model using OData 4 and WebApi I'm struggling a bit with PATCH.
I have created this controller method:

```
[HttpPatch]
public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<EdmEntityObject> delta)
{
  // ...
}
```

When (attemting to) hit it I get the following exception.
Are you supposed to implement your own MediaTypeFormatter? Shouldn't you use application/json? Or is there a trick I'm missing?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The request entity's media type 'application/json' is not supported for this resource.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Delta`1' from content with media type 'application/json'.",
      "type": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
      "stacktrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
    }
  }
}
```